# Is there a built-in function to extract all characters in a string up until the first occurrence of a space?

Tags: vb.net, string

Is there a built-in function to extract all characters in a string up until the first occurrence of a space?

Say the string is:

> Methicillin-resistant staphylococcus aureus

I want to be able to get the substring:

> Methicillin-resistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in *two* functions:

```
newstring = mystring.Substring(0, mystring.IndexOf(" "))
```

Although that will fail if there's no space in `mystring`.

So you could pull out `mystring.IndexOf(" ")` into a variable and check whether it's `-1` (no space found) before you try to use it in `Substring`.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution you can use is a simple IndexOf

```
string GetFirstWord(string source)
{
    int index = source.IndexOf(" ");

    if (index == -1) return source;
    else return source.Substring(0, index);
}
```

The second solution can be used if you want to keep all words into a string array.

```
string[] GetWords(string source)
{
    return source.Split(' ');
}
```

if you only want the first word, you can use it like this :

```
string word = GetWords("Methicillin-resistant staphylococcus aureus")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

And a VB.NET solution. No, it can't be done with one built-in method; you need two:

```
Left(myString, InStr(myString, " ") - 1)
```

And like the other solutions you need to check `InStr` doesn't return `0` if `myString` may not contain a space.